# Structures on the power set (Topological spaces, measurable spaces...)

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, reference-request

When studying topology and measure theory, I've noticed several things in common. The most obvious one is that both subjects study pairs $(X, \Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ satisfying some conditions. I'm looking for a book that treats a generalization of this situations. To be more concrete, I would like a reference that studies categories whose objects are members of some class of pairs $(X, \Omega)$ (maybe $\Omega$ has to be a complete lattice?) and the morphisms are functions $f$ which preserve the structure in the usual sense.

Comment: Neither topologies nor $\sigma$-algebras need to be complete lattices. (They both are lattices, but not necessarily complete). I haven't heard about theory you're interested in, but it seems that the conditions on "the structure" are what is really important in both mentioned cases,  so I wouldn't be surprised if there were none.

Comment: You're right, $\Omega$ doesn't have to be a complete lattice. What I should have written is the following: Maybe the collection of possible $\Omega$ (the possible topologies, or the posible sigma algebras) must be a complete lattice?

Comment: It is standard fact, that intersection of collection of topologies on given space is topology, but sum doesn't have to be. Similarly with $\sigma$-algebras. So in order to have complete lattice, you would have to use ordering different than that given by inclusion, but imo it starts to deviate from the source in that way.

Comment: There's an amusing notion of "pointless topologies." I wonder if there is a notion of "pointless measurable space." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointless_topology

Comment: John Oxtoby's book "Measure and Category" explores the parallel between Topology and Measure Theory, in special between meager sets and zero measure sets. It is a short book (less than 120 pages).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I have found an interesting study about the lattice I described (and concrete categories in general) in the book "Abstract and Concrete Categories: The Joy of Cats" by Adámek, Herrlich, Strecker. The book is available online for free.

Comment: Among other possible versions of this book, it appears the book was originally published in 1990, then a revised version appeared in 2004, then a further revised version appeared in 2006, and it (the 1990 version?) was reprinted by Dover Publications in 2009. Could you be specific about the version of the book you found this in (better yet, if it's in more than one version, mention which ones)? Also, where in the (different versions of the) book -- what pages, sections, etc. -- is the "interesting study" you mention? Finally, if the version(s) you refer to is/are online, provide links.